# android.app.Application cannot be cast Yamba Application?

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest

i have a problem with an android application when i test it in my phone it breaks immediately and i got this error:

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.massine.final_pgm/com.example.massine.final_pgm.BaseActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.massine.final_pgm.YambaApplication"
```

I don't know where the problem came and i read the similar post but i can't fix it: this is my java class and my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.massine.final_pgm">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="com.example.massine.final_pgm.BaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

and my java class:

```
package com.example.massine.final_pgm;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.List;

import winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter;
import winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.Status;

public class YambaApplication extends Application implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
  private static final String TAG = YambaApplication.class.getSimpleName();
  public Twitter twitter; 
  private SharedPreferences prefs;
  private boolean serviceRunning;
  private StatusData statusData;


  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    this.prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    this.statusData = new StatusData(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreated");
  }

  @Override
  public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();
    Log.i(TAG, "onTerminated");
  }

  // Returns the Twitter object
  public synchronized Twitter getTwitter() { 
    if (this.twitter == null) {
      String username = this.prefs.getString("username", null);
      String password = this.prefs.getString("password", null);
      String apiRoot = prefs.getString("apiRoot", "http://yamba.newcircle.com/api");
      if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(username) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)
          && !TextUtils.isEmpty(apiRoot)) {
        this.twitter = new Twitter(username, password);
        this.twitter.setAPIRootUrl(apiRoot);
      }
    }
    return this.twitter;
  }

  // Part of being OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
  public synchronized void onSharedPreferenceChanged( 
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    this.twitter = null;
  }

  public boolean isServiceRunning() {
    return serviceRunning;
  }

  public void setServiceRunning(boolean serviceRunning) {
    this.serviceRunning = serviceRunning;
  }

  public StatusData getStatusData() {
    return statusData;
  }

  public SharedPreferences getPrefs() {
    return prefs;
  }

  // Connects to the online service and puts the latest statuses into DB.
  // Returns the count of new statuses
  public synchronized int fetchStatusUpdates() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching status updates");
    Twitter twitter = this.getTwitter();
    if (twitter == null) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Twitter connection info not initialized");
      return 0;
    }
    try {
      List<Status> statusUpdates = twitter.getFriendsTimeline();
      long latestStatusCreatedAtTime = this.getStatusData()
          .getLatestStatusCreatedAtTime();
      int count = 0;
      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      for (Status status : statusUpdates) {
        values.put(StatusData.C_ID, status.getId());
        long createdAt = status.getCreatedAt().getTime();
        values.put(StatusData.C_CREATED_AT, createdAt);
        values.put(StatusData.C_TEXT, status.getText());
        values.put(StatusData.C_USER, status.getUser().getName());
        Log.d(TAG, "Got update with id " + status.getId() + ". Saving");
        this.getStatusData().insertOrIgnore(values);
        if (latestStatusCreatedAtTime < createdAt) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      Log.d(TAG, count > 0 ? "Got " + count + " status updates"
          : "No new status updates");
      return count;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch status updates", e);
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

The line of the problem is :

```
yamba = ((YambaApplication) getApplication());
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `android:name` on the application element in your manifest file.

`android:name="com.example.massine.final_pgm.YambaApplication"`

Without it the code runs but does not use the YambaApplication class but the default Application which is causing the ClassCastException.

**Edit for clarification based on comment:**

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.massine.final_pgm.YambaApplication"
    ...>
```

Comment: Hi, but when i do it i got this error com.example.massine.final_pgm.YambaApplication is not assignable to android.app.activity.
Validates resource references inside Android XML files ??

Comment: Are you sure you added it to the application and not the activity in your manifest file as shown in my edit?

Comment: <activity android:name="com.example.massine.final_pgm.YambaApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by added it to the application?

PS: the name of my project is FINAL_PGM, and i can't rename it

Comment: Your activity was correct. Do not change it. Add name to the application element not the activity like in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you it works, but what shaal i do in the actvity android name:?

Comment: I'm assuming the activity android:name was just fine so you can put it back to what you had originally. You do have a class named `BaseActivity` that extends `Activity` right?

Comment: Last question, i can't change activities in my app i have this error:
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.massine.final_pgm/com.example.massine.final_pgm.StatusActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: You need to have an <Activity ...> element in your manifest file for each activity your application will use. So add another one for your StatusActivity.